# Copy files from one TFS projects collection to another

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation

What would be a reliable way to copy some files from a project within TFS projects collection A to another project within TFS projects collection B regularly. The latest from source is to be taken and check into the destination, overriding conflicts (if any). I have automated Team Foundation Build and can add a script or step within it. I would prefer this to be a part of automated build but it would also be fine if I had to run it nightly at a fixed time. I just need a reliable and automated way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to investigate the [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2), which allow you to set up synchronization between two TFS servers.  You can set up either bidirectional synchronization or unidirectional synchronization between two servers - in your case, it sounds like you want unidirectional synchronization between collection A and collection B.

We've been using the bidirectional synchronization for about a month now and have been very pleased with it.

Comment: Looks promising. Yes, I need unidirectional sync in a folder structure between two collections. Would you be able to provide more info (links to articles is fine) i.e. how to set this up and any gotchas?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you might want to reconsider that course of action. The boundary between TPCs is meant to be a strong one: they are supposed to be two sandboxes. What would be your reason to port source code (I'm assuming that this what you mean), from one sandbox to another?

If what you really need is the outputs (say you are building a component in one TPC and need to use it in another), then perhaps what you really want to do is to arrange for the project that *builds* the component to deposit the output (binaries, for example) in an accessible network drop location, and have the consumers (the second TPC's developers and automated builds) copy those and add them as references where needed.

This way you do not risk as many conflicts in the code, and actually promote better reusability.

Hope this helps,
Assaf

Comment: The destination TPC is for a team that is completely isolated. It is also readonly for them i.e. they won't modify anything and thus unidirectional sync is fine.